# How to use NSUserDefaults to check between current time and last posting time?

Tags: ios, xcode, date, userdefaults

My idea is that when Button "A" is tapped every time, it will set the NSDate value automatically. When the current time is larger than the existing NSDate value, it print "yes". Here is my code but I dont know what's wrong.
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var currentDateTime = NSDate()

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()

    observeTime()
    }

@IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {
    print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())

}
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

func observeTime() {
    let posttime = userDefaults.object(forKey: "LastPostingTime") as? NSDate

    if ((posttime?.isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare: currentDateTime))!) {
        print("yes")
    }
}


@IBAction func hihi(_ sender: Any) {


    observeTime()
            userDefaults.set(NSDate(), forKey: "LastPostingTime")


}



}

extension NSDate {
func isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
    //Declare Variables
    var isGreater = false

    //Compare Values
    if self.compare(dateToCompare as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
        isGreater = true
    }

    //Return Result
    return isGreater
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated but the `NSDate` extension is very cumbersome. Use `Date` and compare `date1 > date2`. And saving the date and reading it back immediately is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

In function `hihi` you first store the current date into NSUserDefaults before reading it. So you will get back what you just stored: the current time.

You may want to read it first, compare it to currentDateTime and then store it into user defaults.

Comment: could you provide some sample code? Thank u coz I am new to NSUserdefaults

Comment: Just put the first statement in `hihi` at the end.

Comment: I have edited the code on the above but still, I can only compare it on the second tap..(don't know why first tap fails)

Comment: What about debugging? :-) What is the value of posttime for the first call?

Comment: I have tried to print all the value in the log at viewDidLoad, and the value was right. But I could not compare the value with the first tap on the button

Comment: If the value is right, why can't you compare it when the first tap happens?